# How to do validations in sencha extjs mvc application

Tags: validation, extjs

I am working on sencha extjs mvc application. I have created one sample application in mvc pattern but now i want to give some validation to my forms. How can I do the validation in sencha mvc application. please help me out give some example or provide some links for reference.

I have tried for validation as follow:
my model look like this :

```
Ext.define("Usr.model.UserModel", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
    validations: [
        { type: 'format', name: 'id', matcher: /[0-9]+/ },
        { type: 'presence', name: 'name'}
    ]
});
```

Now i want to validate it on form. how can i use this validation on form??

Thanks.

Regards,

Sandy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the model, or otherwise just want to validate it, you can do it like that:

```
var model = MMMM; /* The model you are saving */
var formPanel = FFFF; /* your FormPanel here */;
var validation = model.validate();
if (!validation.isValid()) {
    // This will mark the validation errors on the form:
    formPanel.getForm().markInvalid(validation);
} else {
    // Save your model as usual...
}
```

Comment: ok... but where to validate it like i am having create view and i want its model validation on that view. so where can i validate it like on a controller action which call that view or on to a view or store....

Comment: @Sandy: this validation will usually be placed on the controller as part of the Save/Submit button action.